# generating the regex string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a bag of words and I am trying to find a subset of words in it which matches a pattern. For this, I want to create a regex string which I will be passing as a variable to `re.match()`

For the pattern, I know the length of the word and I know set of characters that does not appear in the string (i.e. `missed_list`) and I know a set of characters that appear in the string (and these characters won't appear again i.e. `hit_list`) and I know the position of these characters (i.e. in the ordered list `cur_state`)
I am having trouble creating this regex string. This is the code I have so far.

```
def get_regex_str(cur_state, hit_list, missed_list):
    skip_letters = ''.join(missed_list)
    skip_letters += ''.join(hit_list)
    regex = "r"
    for c in cur_state:
        if(c == ''):
            regex +="[^"+skip_letters+"]"
        else:
            regex += c
    print regex
    return regex


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hit = ['o']
    missed =['b','n']
    state = ['','o','']
    get_regex_str(state,hit, missed)
    reg = get_regex_str(state,hit, missed)
    print re.match(reg, "mom")
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone advise me how to create this regex string?

The regex string I generate now is `r[^bno]o[^bno]`.

When I evaluate it in the main method output right now is  "None". I was hoping it to be True.

Comment: what's the output (regex) and what's the expected output/behaviour of your regex? with only your code it's unclear (not my downvote (yet) BTW)

Comment: I have added the details. Is it clearer?

Comment: You mention some "length of the word" in the description but have no traces of length restrictions in the code. Could you please clarify this length condition?

Comment: your regex starts with `r` and you expect to match `mom` ? you're mixing up with raw string prefix. Remove `regex = "r"` => `regex = ""`

Comment: the length of the word is `len(state)`. I'm inferring it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks got it!! :) I'm new to regex! Can I also ask is there a better way to write this regex?

Comment: you should rephrase your question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com now that it works. and fix your indentation while you're at it.

Comment: In your example `hit_list` and `missed_list` have no difference. Was the `hit_list` supposed to contain the letters which are mandatory in the word and `missed_list` to contain those which should not present in the word?

Comment: In the skip list, if it contains `-`, it should come last, and if it contains `]`, that should come first - though, in this case, since this is obviously hangman here, `]` probably isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to declare a raw string, then you have to declare it like this:

```
regex = r"foo"
```

Where foo is your regular expression.

```
regex = r"[^{}]".format(skip_letters)
```

Be aware that {} is used in regular expressions as well so you need to take care of how {} will be formatted.